How do update Spring Boot build.gradle to ensure every developer on team is using google-java-format and some general questions
I added the following dependency to the build.gradle file in my branch.
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.24.0'
}

From here, I am confused. How can I ensure that the code formatter is using google-java-format and not the default code formatter? Is installing the plugin from the Marketplace a requirement? I'm trying my best to follow along with the documentation.
The documentation goes on to say "You can then use the formatter through the formatSource methods" and shows an example. Does this mean I have to run the code through those methods each time to Want to format something?

If I'm understanding your question/intent, you want to format your Spring Boot code base/project using google-java-format. If so, then what you have in not correct. You are not intending to develop a library based on google-java-format or tooling, you just want to use it.
If that is correct, then there is a Gradle plugin you can apply to your build that will format your project using google-java-format: Spotless plugin for Gradle.
Apply to your project and configure to use google-java-format:
plugins {
  id("com.diffplug.spotless") version "7.0.0.BETA3"
}


spotless {
  java {
    googleJavaFormat()
  }
}

So the docs for more details here.
